# How to lookup by a string key after GroupBy? Inconsistent data type handling

Tags: bugs, dataset, query

**This is relates to a bug that was introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.1**

**It also relates to an issue that has yet to be corrected.**

---

After applying `GroupBy` to a key all of whose `"values"` are `String`, is it possile to force the internal type representation to subsequently lookup by `"value"` rather than `Key@"value"`?

`GroupBy` modifies internal type representation:

```
titanic = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}];

(* ... Vector[Struct[List["class", "age", "sex", "survived"], 
  List[Atom[Enumeration["1st", "2nd", "3rd"]], Atom[Integer], 
   Atom[Enumeration["female", "male"]], Atom[Boolean]]], AnyLength] ... *)
```

(so does Normal'izing following by casting back to Dataset though `AnyLength` is replaced by a numerical value, eg 1309.)

Even though the keys (formerly values) are String:

```
titanic[GroupBy[Key@"sex"]][Keys, # -> Head[#] &]

(* {"female" -> String, "male" -> String} *)
```

This lookup fails:

```
titanic[GroupBy[Key@"sex"]]["female"]

(* ... Part female is not applicable to <|(Alternatives[Enumeration[female, \
male]] -> _List)..|> ... *)
```

Note: lookup query `Key@"female"` works. Strangely, works also without `Key` when `KeyDrop` is applied before `GroupBy`:

`titanic[All, KeyDrop["survived"]][GroupBy[Key@"sex"]]["female"]`

```
(* ... {<|"class" -> "1st", "age" -> 29, "sex" -> "female"|>, ... *)
```

Conversely, if `Span` substitutes `KeyDrop`, the data are the same

```
titanic[All, 1 ;; 3][GroupBy[Key@"sex"]][Keys, # -> Head[#] &]

(* {"female" -> String, "male" -> String} *)
```

but lookup also fails even using `Key`:

```
titanic[All, 1 ;; 3][GroupBy[Key@"sex"]][Key@"female"]

(* ... Key Key["female"] is not one of {}. ... *)
```

I'm not sure how to interpret that message: b/c the internal the representation is `AnyType`:

```
Assoc[Atom[AnyType], 
 Vector[Assoc[Atom[String], Atom[AnyType], 3], AnyLength], AnyLength]
```

How to handle these various cases uniformly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue here is already fixed in 10.0.1 (probably as a side-effect of fixes for some of the other typesystem bugs that have already been reported by you and others!).

The span issue is separate, I've reported that (thanks!)

Comment: Should we tag this question as a bug in that case?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard sure. How does one do that?

Comment: If you "hover" the mouse pointer next to the existing tags, which presently are `dataset` and `query` you should see "edit tags" appear.  If you click that you can edit the tags.  I shall add `bugs` now.  Please add this tag to any question/report about a confirmed bug that you see.

Answer (score 3):

Until this bug is fixed, a work-around is to avoid the operator form of `GroupBy`, e.g.:

```
titanic[GroupBy[#, Key@"sex"]& /* "female"]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

This same bug affects many operator forms, but this work-around frequently dodges it.