# Group dataset on two keys (GroupBy)

Tags: grid-layouts, dataset

I would like to group the elements of row c of the following  dataset according to the values in the columns a and b. That is

**Go from here**

[image: dataset2]

**To here**

[image: grp]

And then I would like to print this on a grid, without visible lists (like {2,7})

```
    1      2
 x  1      4
 y  2 
    7  
 z  7      8
```

**Code**

This is the dataset I used

```
dataset2 = Dataset[{
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> 1|>,
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "y", "c" -> 2|>,
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "z", "c" -> 7|>,
<|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "x", "c" -> 4|>,
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "y", "c" -> 7|>,
<|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "z", "c" -> 8|>}]
```

and this is the dataset2 after grouping on columns a an b

```
grp = Dataset[{<|"b" -> "x", "a=1" -> {1}, 
"a=2" -> {4}|>, <|"b" -> "x", "a=1" -> {2, 7}, 
"a=2" -> {}|>, <|"b" -> "x", "a=1" -> {7}, "a=2" -> {8}|>} ]
```

**Example from the help**

that comes close to what I want to do

```
dataset = Dataset[{
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
<|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
<|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
<|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
<|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
<|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}]
```

[image: dataset]

```
dataset[GroupBy[Key["b"]], Catenate, "c"]
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand the intermediate output that you want as you did not give it in `Dataset` form, but I believe the grouping you want can be done with this:

```
ds = dataset2[GroupBy[{#b &, #a &}], All, All, Extract["c"]];

ds // Normal
```

> ```
> <|"x" -> <|1 -> {1}, 2 -> {4}|>, "y" -> <|1 -> {2, 7}|>, "z" -> <|1 -> {7}, 2 -> {8}|>|>
> ```

From there you might use something like this:

```
TableForm[
  ds[Values, Values] // Normal,
  TableHeadings -> {Normal @ Keys[ds], {1, 2}}
]
```

[image]

---

Correction; this part of my code is wrong:

```
ds[Values, Values] // Normal
```

It merely happens to work for the example given but if the `"y"` group had been under `2` it would be wrong.  I can't think of a clean way to solve this, and what want to use doesn't work, I think because of this bug:

- [How to lookup by a string key after GroupBy? Inconsistent data type handling](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58167/121)

Hopefully WReach will stop by and give is a workaround. :-)

Comment: You can correct the problem you describe by replacing `ds[Values, Values]` with this ugliness: `ds[Values /* (KeyUnion[#, {} &] &)][All, Values]`.  It fills in absent keys, ensuring that the columns "line up".  This could all probably be baked into a single query but I, like you, am not sure what to make of that intermediate result.  Oh, and I'm sure that we'd also run into the operator-form bug you reference.  The type information in `ds` is messed up as written, but it can be fixed up by changing the `GroupBy` operator form to an explicit function (`GroupBy[#, ...]&`).